# Query to pull data based on combined same name, sum quantity based on item condition

Tags: google-sheets, excel-formula, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying to build a simple inventory management system on a google sheet. Right now I'm stuck on something that I couldn't figure out how to solve. So I'm seeking help to solve this issue.

In my `Purchase DB` sheet I have row data column `A` is the Item name, column `B` is the Item quantity, column `C` is for a unit of measure & column `D` is for item condition:

[image]

I want a query or formula that pulls this row data and then combined similar item name sum quantity & which must be separated by the item conditions. I mean the same item name:

[image]

Please use this google sheet** [Click here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1ApeBDsHW0MmcL0EMUxB41JqC-5POHE6cTOj6ydt4hsc/edit?usp=sharing).

I'm looking forward someone to answering my question.

I have already tried a query

```
=QUERY(A2:D, "select A, sum(B) group by A ")
```

but I'm not satisfied with the results:

[image]

Comment: Make sure to add input and expected output as **text table** (NOT as IMAGE/LINK) to the question. [Click here](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/161855/) to create a table easily. Adding such tables greatly increases your chances of getting a elegant answer, as **it is easier to copy/paste**. If you share spreadsheets, your question maybe closed, as questions here must be [self contained](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/260455). Your table should be a [mre].[Your email address can also be accessed by the public](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394304/), if you share Google files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=QUERY(A1:D, "select A, sum(B),C,D group by A,C,D Order by A desc LABEL sum(B) 'Quantity'",1)
```

This should do the work.

Tested in you sheet with you values and return correct result

Comment: Hi, @Neo thanks for responding to my question. I have tried your query & it is working absolutely fine except for one thing the row after the header is blank. is there any way to prevent that?

Comment: Resolved, not by me though, thanks to ever aded the `desc` in the order by